# How to replace invalid UTF8 chars with spaces

Tags: perl, unix, utf-8

I have a fixed width file that has some non UTF8 chars, I want to replace the non UTF8 chars with space.

I tried to run `iconv -f utf8 -t utf8 -c $file` 
but the only thing it does it removes the non UTF8 chars. There is no way to replace them with spaces by using iconv.

I would like to have a korn shell script / perl script to replace all non-utf8 chars with spaces.

I found this perl script that prints the lines where non-utf8 chars are found, but I don't know anything about perl to make it do replace the non-UTF8 with spaces.

```
perl -l -ne '/
   ^( [\000-\177]                 # 1-byte pattern
     |[\300-\337][\200-\277]      # 2-byte pattern
     |[\340-\357][\200-\277]{2}   # 3-byte pattern
     |[\360-\367][\200-\277]{3}   # 4-byte pattern
     |[\370-\373][\200-\277]{4}   # 5-byte pattern
     |[\374-\375][\200-\277]{5}   # 6-byte pattern
    )*$ /x or print' FILE.dat
```

environment AIX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl's Encode module has this ability.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw(encode decode);

while (<>) {
   # decode the utf-8 bytes and make them into characters
   # and turn anything that's invalid into U+FFFD
   my $string = decode("utf-8", $_);

   # change any U+FFFD into spaces
   $string =~ s/\x{fffd}/ /g;

   # turn it back into utf-8 bytes and print it back out again
   print encode("utf-8", $string);
}
```

Or the smaller command line version:

```
perl -pe 'use Encode; $_ = Encode::decode("utf-8",$_); s/\x{fffd}/ /g; $_ = Encode::encode("utf-8", $_)'
```